# Problems with creating Observable when using @escaping closures

Tags: swift, core-data, rx-swift

I am trying to code an observable for `NSManagedObjectContext` `save()` operation with no success. The function does not fire neither `onNext` nor `onCompleted` event and is being disposed immediately. When I debug with breakpoints it shows `Disposables.create()` and `@escaping` notification closure work on different threads. Please tell what am I doing wrong in the code below and help to fix the problem.

```
func save() -> Observable<Void> {
    guard base.hasChanges else { return Observable.just(()) }
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
        var token: NSObjectProtocol?
        token = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: self, queue: nil) { _ in
            observer.onNext(()) /* Is executed on the other thread and is never called */
            observer.onCompleted()
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(token!)
        }
        
        base.perform {
            do {
                try base.save()
            } catch {
                observer.onError(Error.some)
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create() \* Immediately calls this func *\
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use RxSwift, but my guess is that it's because `base.perform` returns immediately. Try using `base.performAndWait`.

Comment: In case I use performAndWait it works on the same thread but blocks the UI when saving large files. Therefore I tried to code it asynchronously.

Comment: Is there any chance you can post a compilable example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func save() -> Observable<Void> {
    guard base.hasChanges else { return Observable.just(()) }
    return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Save")
        queue.sync {
            self.base.perform {
                do {
                    try self.base.save()
                    observer.onNext(())
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } catch {
                    observer.onError(NSManagedObjectContext.ReactiveError.save)
                }
            }                
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this should work:

```
func save() -> Observable<Void> {
    Observable.create { observer in
        base.perform {
            do {
                try base.save()
                observer.onNext(())
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
            catch {
                observer.onError(error)
            }
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! According to apple Dev docs we can neither do it this way .subscribe(on: SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .background)) nor via DispatchGoup.async but use context.perform (async) or context.performAndWait (sync).

Comment: I fixed the bug in my code and made it even simpler than the first variant. The main problem Observable early disposal hid in my further code - I disposed it by .dispose(by: DisposeBag()) not by dispose(by: bag) where bag = DisposeBag() declared as class property.